# Excel line graph do not show next weeks with na()

Tags: excel, graph

I have an excel grid with a weekly graph.
The Value of the weekly graphs are all formulas and it looks like this:

```
19-Feb-15             314
26-Feb-15             319
5-Mar-15              356
12-Mar-15             #N/A
19-Mar-15             #N/A
26-Mar-15             #N/A
```

If I select the line graph's value up to 26 March then it gives me 3 gaps for 12 March, 19 March and 26 March. But I would like the graph to end on 5 March and not give me these gaps.

Then next week when I add a value on 12 March it will automatically add it to the line graph and show no gaps for 19 and 26 March.

I hope that's clear enough.

If the above is not doable, then maybe you have a VBA code which I could use so someone can simply click a button so it updates the graph with the data from the last 12 weeks.

Tks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to look at the x-axis and convert it to a category axis or whatever they call it in Excel.

Comment: Are you willing to make another column of data?

Comment: some reading for you. 3 great posts on plotting gaps in data, all from peltiertech.com: http://peltiertech.com/mind-the-gap-charting-empty-cells/, http://peltiertech.com/vba-approaches-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/, http://peltiertech.com/another-approach-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/

Comment: Yes @chancea, I am willing to create another column if needed.

Comment: Tks @guitarthrower I did not know you could put a formula as part of the grid selection. Does that mean I could do something like ISNUMBER(A2:A500)<>NA())

Comment: @pnuts removing the #N/A won't handle it, it will still create a gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to create an extra column, assuming your data starts in column A then you can simple put this formula in column C:

```
=IF(ISERROR(B1),NA(),A1)
```

So your data would look like:

```
    A        B                C
19-Feb-15   314     =IF(ISERROR(B1),NA(),A1)
26-Feb-15   319     =IF(ISERROR(B2),NA(),A2)
05-Mar-15   356     =IF(ISERROR(B3),NA(),A3)
12-Mar-15   #N/A    =IF(ISERROR(B4),NA(),A4)
19-Mar-15   #N/A    =IF(ISERROR(B5),NA(),A5)
26-Mar-15   #N/A    =IF(ISERROR(B6),NA(),A6)
```

Which turns to:

```
    A        B         C
19-Feb-15   314     19-Feb-15
26-Feb-15   319     26-Feb-15
05-Mar-15   356     05-Mar-15
12-Mar-15   #N/A    #N/A
19-Mar-15   #N/A    #N/A
26-Mar-15   #N/A    #N/A
```

Then if you keep column B as your Y values but you now select column C as your X values the graph will automatically adjust as you enter data:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! I got inspired by your code and figured out an even better way to do it (without adding another column): I simply wrote =IF(B2="",NA(),A1+7)

Comment: Sorry, I meant =IF(ISERROR(B2),NA(),A1+7)